# How to build a HTML from JSON and JQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-templates

I know I'm messing up the syntax somewhere but I can't figure out where. Code below. (I left out the body tag because it wasn't showing correctly in the preview)

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.tmplPlus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="ProductsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <table class="productsHere">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>Size</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{each data}}
                    {{tmpl($value) '#ProductsRowTemplate'}}
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>            
        </table>
    </script>
    <script id="ProductsRowTemplate" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td class="title">${title}</td>
            <td class="size">${size}</td>
            <td class="price">${price}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>
    <title>Using JQuery</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "JSON-WebService.asmx/getProducts",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ProductsTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#ProductsTable');
                alert("It works");
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert("It didn't work");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="ProductsTable"></div>
<div id="OthersTable"></div>
<div></div>

</form>
```

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: Based on my alert, I can get: "It works", but the table isn't rendering. All I see is the header. I'm not getting an error message either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5+ and getProducts returns a collection like a List or an array, you'll need to account for [the .d that .NET wraps your data with](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/).  Since your `{{each}}` loop needs a reference to the array anyway, you can take advantage of the .d by changing your template like so:

```
<script id="ProductsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <table class="productsHere">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{each d}}
        {{tmpl($value) '#ProductsRowTemplate'}}
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh. Okay, I'm getting the correct amount of rows, but I'm getting the Header 9 times (there's 9 records in the actual database table, so that part is correct). And yes, I'm using .NET 4.0, and the webservice is returning an array.

Comment: I changed my mind, and updated my answer. Since your `{{each}}` needs a reference to loop over anyway, just pass in `data` instead of `data.d` and then use the `.d` to specify what you want to loop over.  That will solve your problem of seeing the header repeated 9 times instead of the `{{tmpl}}` being executed 9 times.